# How can I get Axios to send a request with FormData?

Tags: node.js, axios, multipartform-data

I'm unable to get the server that I'm calling to recognize the FormData that I'm providing when I use `axios`. It keeps telling me that I'm not providing the right FormData even though it works in Postman and Node native http (see below):

```
import { Router } from "express";
import axios from "axios";
import * as FormData from "form-data";

const router = Router();
const cookieHeader = {
    Cookie: "XXX",
};

router.get("/", async (_req, res) => {
    try {
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("key1", JSON.stringify(["value1"]));
        formData.append("key2", "value2");
        formData.append("key3", "value3");

        const response = await axios.post("https://xxx", formData, { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------811161660471543283806813" } });

        res.send(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am able to get it working in Postman and used that to export using Node's native http, which also works:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { https } from "follow-redirects";

const router = Router();

router.get("/", () => {
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        hostname: "xxx",
        path: "/xx/xxx",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------811161660471543283806813",
            Cookie: "xxx",
        },
        maxRedirects: 20,
    };

    const req = https.request(options, (res: any) => {
        const chunks: any[] = [];

        res.on("data", (chunk: any) => {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("end", () => {
            const body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            console.log(body.toString());
        });

        res.on("error", (error: any) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    });

    const postData = `------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key1\"\n\n[\"value1\"]\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key2\"\n\nvalue2\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key3\"\n\nvalue3\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--`;

    req.setHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");

    req.write(postData);

    req.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out after reading through https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/318. It wasn't until near the end that Googrosh posted that he used `.getHeaders()`. Lo and behold, I added that to my headers too and it worked.

So updating my code, here's what it looks like:

```
const response = await axios.post("https://xxx", formData, { headers: formData.getHeaders() });
```

Comment: how to do this in the browser ? `formData.getHeaders()` doesn't work there !

Answer (score -1):

```
onst formUrlEncoded = x =>
   Object.keys(x).reduce((p, c) => p + `&${c}=${encodeURIComponent(x[c])}`, '')

var axios = require("axios");

axios({
  url: 'https://login.xyz.com/oauth/v2/token',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data: formUrlEncoded({
     client_id: '***',
     client_secret: '***',
     grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  })
})
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.data)
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: What is `onst`?  Was this tested or checked before posting?   Also, what @Tyler2P said about code-only answers.